# Can you tell me more about global configuration

Tags: flutter, configuration, global

I have read in flutter.dev about global_configuration it is:

```
"A flutter package for managing different configurations by merging them together and making them available everythere inside the app via a singleton."
```

[this link of global_configuration library](https://pub.dev/packages/global_configuration)
but honestly i didn't understand much about what the library dose i searched in youtube and google didn't find much about it if you can tell me where to use it and what its benefit i would very glad and thank you..

Comment: check [Loading configuration](https://pub.dev/packages/global_configuration#loading-configuration)

Comment: Yes but i didn't understand where to use the loading configuration that is my question..

Comment: where to use the configuration in your app? anywhere you want its data - for example inside your `build()` method